# Why my Dockerfile for NextJS app very slow when building image and has huge size

Tags: node.js, docker, next.js, monorepo, nrwl-nx

I've NX monorepo with a NextJS web-app. It's s very simple, just one page with "hello world", with no assets and images.

I've made a Dockerfile for my webapp, below is my Dockerfile, and here are my 3 questions:

1. it's dramatically slow on build, it takes more than 15 min to build image, also the image is more than 1.5Gb.
2. on the NX website I found an example how to configure Nx+NextJS+vercel but didn't found example of clean Dockerfile without tying to any hosting provider, so maybe somebody could advice what's wrong with my Dockerfile
3. not sure re last instruction: is it correct to run nextjs app with just "npm start" for production

```
FROM node:16-alpine AS deps
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile


FROM node:16-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .
RUN npx nx build webappName --prod


FROM node:16-alpine AS runner
WORKDIR /app
ENV NODE_ENV production
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nextgroup
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextuser
COPY --from=builder /app/dist/apps/webappName ./
USER nextuser
EXPOSE 3000
ENV PORT 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: Q: Why is it dramatically slow on build, taking more than 15 min to build image, also the image is more than 1.5Gb? A: If you figure out why it's 1.5GB ... that will probably also explain why the build is slow!  This article might help troubleshoot exactly what's happening at each stage of your build:  https://www.joyfulbikeshedding.com/blog/2019-08-27-debugging-docker-builds.html.  See also:  https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/16995